# Как корректно контроллировать количество подключений?

Tags: postgresql

Допустим мы можем узнать количество активных подключений следующим образом:

```
SELECT
  usename,
  count(*)
FROM
  pg_stat_activity
GROUP BY
  usename
ORDER BY
  usename
```

Теперь один из клиентов отключается...
Но в данном списке он остаётся висеть ещё неопределённое время.
Это проблема настройки сервера?
Некорректного отключения клиента?
PostgreSQL? Подскажите каким образом можно получить актуальное состояние подключений на данный момент.

Answer (score 1):

добавьте `state` в запрос. если `state` = 'idle in transaction`значит используется`session pooling`, и для сервера сессия не заканчивается. пулер не закрывает сессии при отключении клиента, а возвращает в пул:

```
t=# SELECT
  usename,
  state,
  count(*)
FROM
  pg_stat_activity
GROUP BY
  usename,
  state
ORDER BY
  usename
;
 usename  | state  | count
----------+--------+-------
 vao      | idle   |     3
 postgres | active |     1
 postgres | idle   |     1
(3 rows)
```